# iText 7.1.5 get real width of table from CSV

Tags: java, itext7

Currently I use iText `7.1.5` version and try to convert CSV file to PDF.
When completing the table, I can't provide the correct page size to contain the entire table.

Before that version I used `7.1.1` and this code worked for me:

```
Table pdfTable = new Table(columnCount).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                // sets WIDTH property of table
                .useAllAvailableWidth();
        Cell cell = new Cell();

        cell.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY).setBold();
        pdfTable.addHeaderCell(cell);

        // headers and content
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            //...
            pdfTable.addHeaderCell(cell);
        }

        PageSize fittedPageSize = PDFUtility.getFittedPageSize(pdfTable.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getWidth());
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(fittedPageSize);

        document.add(pdfTable);
```

Now the `pdfTable.getWidth()` returns 100% which is true because `useAllAvailableWidth` call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have 2 different questions. Please ask separate questions. Thank you.

Comment: You yourself say *"Now the `pdfTable.getWidth()` returns 100% which is true because `useAllAvailableWidth` call."* I.e. the table size depends on the page size. Thus, which width exactly do you hope to retrieve?

Comment: @mkl I want to fit the page size to the table width. Therefore I need the true table width. Thanks.

Comment: But as you say yourself, the *true table width* depends on the page size. Or do you mean by *true table width* something like the minimum table width?

Comment: "do you mean by true table width something like the minimum table width" - yes. And for the first part of your comment, even with page size of A4 the table doesn't  fit itself.

Comment: @Michael Azarzar you say that the code worked in iText 7.1.1. But I doubt it, because `useAllAvailableWidth` method was performing the same (setting the `100%` value on a table) and `getWidth` was (and is) just a getter.

Could you expand on it? Could you share the result of `pdfTable.getWidth()` in 7.1.1?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/hbeyd48) this is sample of the table from `7.1.1`. Except the result the code is same. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As answer to another question of mine, @Uladzimir Asipchuk gave me solution that can fit here too.

This is the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747195/calculate-the-width-of-a-table-in-itext-7).

And my code:

```
`Table pdfTable = new Table(columnCount).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
.useAllAvailableWidth();
// Add table content here
MinMaxWidth minMaxWidth = 
((TableRenderer)pdfTable.createRendererSubTree()
.setParent(document.getRenderer())).getMinMaxWidth();
float minWidth = minMaxWidth.getMaxWidth(); 
pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PDFUtility
.getFittedPageSize(minWidth,PageSize.A4.getWidth()));
document.add(pdfTable);`
```